# No live boot from usb and restarting with a blinking white underscore in Ubuntu [HP Laptop] , Not taking any command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, hardware

My PC suddenly stopped responding after reboot. I tried using a **bootable USB** but nothing is appearing. I tried removing the battery too.

Is this a hardware issue or my Ubuntu image is encrypted? A week ago it was showing some encryption issue.

I tried all these [1](https://www.servethehome.com/fix-blinking-cursor-black-screen-ubuntu-installation/) , [2](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/559085/help-blinking-underscore-black-screen-will-not-boot-or-safe-mode/) , [3](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/computer-stuck-on-black-screen-with-blinking-underscore/) , [4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-open-to-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor-after-upgrading-from-12-10-to-1) , [5](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836977).

Comment: When you say you've tried a bootable USB but "_nothing is appearing_", that would suggest you're not successfully booting from the USB stick. They intentionally do not boot quietly and you should have seen something. Get that sorted first.

Comment: Anything to see when pressing `ESC`?

Comment: No, nothing is appearing. I am applying the right way to boot @roaima